# EmguCV compatible version for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, dll, emgucv, face-recognition

I am working on Image processing and i have made an application in c# using EmguCV wrapper version 2.4 beta and now i want to covert it in to vb.Net so which version would be compatible for vb.Net i want to use these dll files.

```
Imports Emgu.CV.UI
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports Emgu.CV.CvEnum
```

Help me to resolve this problem how can i use EmguCV in vb.Net..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same version of visual studio that you used to create your c# project (or newer). Target the same version of the .net framework in each (or newer). Reference the same EnguCV dlls in each.

Functionally the languages are almost identical, however if your c# app uses `unsafe` code blocks then stay with c# as they're not supported in vb.net

Comment: Thanks it really helped me.. @FloatingKiwi

Comment: No problem and welcome to the site. Please mark the solution as accepted so that it helps others in the future.